# Error:(2) Attribute "color" has already been defined (adding support:design lib)

Tags: android, android-support-library

I'm using these imports in my gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.1'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.1'
compile 'com.splunk.mint:mint:4.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

In my lib folder there are:

```
gcm.jar
org.apache.http.legacy.jar
ZSDK_ANDROID_API.jar
```

My long lasting Android project is working fine with that structure until I add 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1' to it.

When I create a completely new project, it is working just fine with support:design import added (and all the other ones from my project, even the lib folder). Which leads to the conclusion that something in my project source code collides with something from support:design, but I have no idea what.

Any clues or thoughts?

EDIT:
The error code goes like this:

```
C:\(path_to_my_project)\res\values\colors.xml Error:(2) Attribute "color" has already been defined

Error:Execution failed for task ':(my_project):processProductionDebugResources'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

It's not showing me the line in color.xml where the collision is.

Gradle setting are:

```
compileSdkVersion 23 
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "(my_project_package)"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
}
```

Comment: post please the error message.

Comment: Have you changed the targetsdk and buildtools version also to 23.x.x ?

Comment: I've updated the question. Building with the latest buildtools and targetSDK as you can see. It's driving me mad for months now and I finally got here to ask a question (because all the other ones from stack didn't solve anything).